# how to get single Popper to render in mapping using React usePopper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

I have a mapping in a `reactstrap` table. The first `<td>` of every row should open a popper/tooltip like this:

[image: design to reproduce]

I added the popper to my code using `usePopper` hook from `react-popper` library.

I'm successfully rendering the `popper` but since the element is inside a mapping I'm currently triggering the state on all the poppers of the table:

[image: current localhost]

This is my code:

```
  const boxRef = useRef()
  const tooltipRef = useRef()

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const { styles, attributes } = usePopper(boxRef.current, tooltipRef.current)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }
```

```
<tbody>
  {playersDetailTable.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <tr className={stylesModule.table_row_PlayersManagementTable} key={index}>
          <td style={nicknameStyles} ref={boxRef} onClick={handleClick}>
            {item.nickname}
            {/* NICKNAME POPPER */}
            <div
              {...attributes.popper}
              ref={tooltipRef}
              className={`${stylesModule.Tooltip} ${
                !isOpen ? stylesModule.Tooltip__hidden : null
              }`}
            >
              {item.nickname}
            </div>
            {/* NICKNAME POPPER */}
          </td>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.lastName}</td>
          <td>{item.portal}</td>
          <td>{item.affiliate}</td>
          <td className='text-center'>
            <img src={item.countryImg} alt='Country flag' height={12} width={16} />Ï
          </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I show only the correct popper when `isOpen` state is set to true while keeping the popper element inside the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the popper outside of the table mapping, and saved the popper data in a new state `const [popperData, setPopperData] = useState(null)`.

I'm setting the data for the single popper and opening it every time the user clicks on the nickname table cell inside the mapping, achieving the result I wanted

```
<td
  style={nicknameStyles}
  ref={boxRef}
  onClick={() => {
    setPopperData(item)
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }}
>
  {item.nickname}
</td>
```